# At what MP does Inferno Act I is better than Act IV Hell, and each Act of Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

I finished Hell difficulty with MP 10, but I can't do Inferno on MP 10, so at what MP level am I better off farming Act I Inferno, than Act IV Hell on MP 10?

The same goes for the different Acts in Inferno, what MP levels are equivalent between the different Acts.

Equivalence in respect to

- loot drop rate per item level
- gold drop rate per enemy killed
- and XP per enemy killed

Comment: this depends highly on your clearing speed i.e. dps and class

Comment: @spartacus, How is it dependant? I don't ask about rates per time, I'm asking about the xp and drop rates in general.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed because you asked for "better" citing three different metrics, gold and XP will depend heavily on your clearing speed. I would suggest editing your question to be specific to loot drop rate based on item level, which is something that can be answered more definitively without taking clearing speed into account. XP per hour is going to depend heavily on your clearing speed, since even Nightmare difficulty would be faster XP than Inferno if you keep getting killed by the same enemy.

Comment: @Kalina, Is it clearer now?

Comment: we'll see, I don't have an answer for you either way I was just clarifying @spartacus' point

Comment: Is it clear now what I meant, and can THIS question be answered regardless of class, build and stats?

Comment: it's clear what you meant, but anything related to speed (ie: XP per hour) is going to depend on many things, not least "how good you are at the game", "your class", "your gear", etc

Comment: the reason why this is so stats dependent is, 'best' xp is only if you can 1 shot everything.  If you don't care about rate and want xp per monster, then of course its a no brainer mp10 is the best for that, but if your dps is only 100k, then you are better off clearing low MPs.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Diablo_III_Patches):

> Experience awarded by level 61-63 monsters has been increased by approximately 60%

and

> The drop rates for high-end items (items level 61-63) have been
> increased for Acts III and IV of Hell difficulty and Acts I – IV of
> Inferno difficulty The new approximate drop rates are as follows:
>
> Hell – Act III and Act IV
>
> - iLvl 61: 9% to 13.9%
> - iLvl 62: 1.9% to 3.45%
> - iLvl 63: 0% (no change)
>
> Inferno – Act I
>
> - iLvl 61: 17.7% to 23.9%
> - iLvl 62: 7.9% to 12.6%
> - iLvl 63: 2.0% to 4.8%
>
> Inferno – Act II
>
> - iLvl 61: 18.6% to 23.3%
> - iLvl 62: 12.4% to 18.6%
> - iLvl 63: 4.1% to 9.3%
>
> Inferno – Act III and Act IV
>
> - iLvl 61: 24.1% to 27.1%
> - iLvl 62: 16.1% to 21.7%
> - iLvl 63: 8.0% to 16.3%

Also, don't forget that `One key detail is that Monster Power grants very different bonuses and changes while on Normal/Nightmare/Hell difficulties, compared to Inferno difficulty. For the first three difficulties, while characters are still leveling up and not yet finding end game quality gear, the following changes can be enabled.` ([source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Monster_Power))

And this one: `Players should now encounter more monsters in Acts I, II, and IV in Inferno difficulty when playing at Monster Power 1 or greater` ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/9647272/patch-108-now-live-5-7-2013))

Here are 2 tables with the effects of Monster Power(both pictures taken from [`DiabloWiki`](http://www.diablowiki.net)):

[image]
[image]

So answering your questions:

- Even at MP0 you will get better loot in Inferno than in Hell(as we know, even MP1 buffs all monsters in Inferno to level 63, so try to play with at least MP1 for much better results)
- *Didn't find any information about that yet*
- You may get more XP per enemy killed at Hell MP10 rather than at Inferno MP1, but you will encounter more enemies which will lead to more kills and more overall XP.

And if you can do Hell MP10, I assume that you can also do Inferno MP3-4. If it is the case: go to inferno!

Hope it helps

Comment: The MP bonuses for Inferno were changed at [patch 1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8608455/patch-107-now-live-2-12-2013)

Comment: @IlyaMelamed yes, but you will still get more exp from Hell MP10 monster(+200% XP), than you will from Inferno MP1 monster(+25% XP)

Comment: @novarg Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you get the same amount of XP for slaying monsters in Hell and in Inferno. You can't conclude "Hell MP10 is better", because say Normal MP10, will give you +200% XP, but killing a monster there probably will still give you nothing comparable to a monster in MP0 inferno.